# Seam3 Solder logging

Tags: logging, seam3

I've just started using Seam Solder and their logging module looks interesting http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/solder/latest/reference/en-US/html/logging.html

See code at bottom of post for my test example.

A few issues that has risen from trying to use it:

- How to inject a normal log4j Logger object? The documentation just has `@Inject Logger log`, which seems simple enough, but it throws an exception at deploy time: `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Logger] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject com.company.application.controller.SessionController.log]`
- Besides from injecting a normal logger, Typed loggers also seemed pretty nifty. The documentation claims you should use the `@LogMessage` annotation, which does not exist. My guess is that it was renamed to `@Log` since this seems to work. To enable use of all normal methods (info, warning, error, etc), letting the log interface extend `BasicLogger` seemed easy enough, but this interface doesn't seem to be annotated correctly, so nothing is actually logged when these methods are called (the invocation handler checks for `@Message` annotation and finds none). Am I doing something wrong or is the framework just really unfinished? Should I perhaps stick with normal log4j when developing a system going into prod in a few months?

Interface

```
@MessageLogger
public interface SessionLogger extends BasicLogger{

    @Message("User %s logged in. Redirecting to %s.")
    @Log(level= Level.INFO)
    void login(String username, String to);

    @Message("User %s logged out.")
    void logout(String username);
}
```

Usage

```
@Inject SessionLogger log

...

log.login("username", "url");
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the Annotations you are doing are the Solder Annotations, and not the generic ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like a dependency problen on classes included in Seam Solder. Are you sure the dependency is satisfied ?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.seam.solder</groupId>
  <artifactId>seam-solder</artifactId>
  <version>${version.seam}</version>
</dependency>
```